# How do i check if an email address exists when user signup (Angularjs and Firebase)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, firebase, angularfire

I am currently working on a project thats using firebase and angularjs and i want my application to check if an email already exists everytime a user try to create an account.

here is HTML markup:

```
<div class="well text-center">
  <h1 class="text-info"><i class="fa fa-group socio_icon"></i></h1>
    <h1>Blog title</h1>
    <p class="lead">Slogan goes here</p>

    <form name="signup_form" novalidate autocomplete="off">
        <p>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg" ng-class="{'has-error': signup_form.fullnames.$dirty && signup_form.fullnames.$invalid , 'has-success': signup_form.fullnames.$valid}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter full names" name="fullnames" ng-model="signup.form" ng-minlength=5 ng-maxlength=45 required />
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.fullnames.$dirty && signup_form.fullnames.$valid"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.fullnames.$dirty && signup_form.fullnames.$invalid"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-warning"></i></span>
          </div>
            </p>

          <p>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg" ng-class="{'has-error': signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$invalid , 'has-success': signup_form.email.$valid}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" name="email" ng-model="signup.email" ng-minlength=5 ng-maxlength=45 required />
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$valid"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$invalid"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-warning"></i></span>
            </p>

          <p>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg" ng-class="{'has-error': signup_form.password1.$dirty && signup_form.password1.$invalid , 'has-success': signup_form.password1.$valid}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password1" ng-model="password1" ng-pattern="/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/" ng-minlength=6 ng-maxlength=45 required />
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.password1.$dirty && signup_form.password1.$valid"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.password1.$dirty && signup_form.password1.$invalid"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-warning"></i></span>
          </div>

            </p>

            <p>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg" ng-class="{'has-error': signup_form.password2.$dirty && signup_form.password2.$invalid , 'has-success': signup_form.password2.$valid}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" ng-model="password2" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/" required placeholder="Re-enter password"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.password2.$dirty && signup_form.password2.$valid"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon valid" ng-show="signup_form.password2.$dirty && signup_form.password2.$invalid"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-warning"></i></span>
          </div>

      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="signup_form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Singup and enjoy!
        </button>
      </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/');


  });
```

Comment: This might be of help http://blog.mailgun.com/post/free-email-validation-api-for-web-forms/ (also this; https://github.com/mailgun/flanker)

Comment: thanks, but my application is based on Angularjs and Firebase

Comment: You may check if the address validates on some RFC spec - you know, contains an @ and a . and a TLD - but really, the ONLY way to be sure is to send a verification e-mail. It always annoys me if my address name+somebogussitenameidliketofilter@gmail.com gets rejected because there's a + sign in it. EDIT: sorry, I misread your question. You want to check for uniqueness of an e-mail address? Just do a query on whatever database you use, right?

Comment: Hello Eric, it will help when posting here on SO to make sure you specify as much detail as possible, and also outline some samples of what you've tried so far. That way you don't get so many cursory comments completely unrelated to your question  :)

Comment: @Kato thanks for an advice, I have pasted my sample

Answer (score 4):

The typical method for checking existence of records in Firebase is to use an index. Since firebase does not certain characters in [references](https://www.firebase.com/docs/creating-references.html), you will need to escape the email first.

Since this is a common question I have a [gist showing how to do this](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6936352).

The "gist", to forgive a pun, is that you need to create an index whenever you create users, and then check that index:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);

function isDuplicateEmail(email, callback) {
  fb.child('email_index/'+escapeEmail(email)).once('value', function(snap) {
     callback( snap.val() !== null );
  });
}

function updateUser(user_id, email) {
   fb.child('user/'+user_id).set({email: email});
   fb.child('email_index/'+escapeEmail(email)).set(user_id);
}

function escapeEmail(email) {
  return (email || '').replace('.', ',');
}
```

Comment: In this case we need to let email_index free from restriction, right? It means anyone can see the list o emails of my application?

Comment: No Doug, you only need read access to the specific email address (i.e. `email_index/$specificemail`) not to `email_index/`; this means they can only see if a specific email address exists.